# Reading Elevation Data from DSM file using Python or QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, dem, elevation

I am new to GIS processing and I have a DSM file with a .tif extension. I would like to read the elevation data from this file using Python or QGIS.

I can view this file on the delair web application like below.

[image]

The objective is to identify the mounds you can see in the center of the image using elevation data , However, I am not even able to read it.
Things which I have tried:

- Installed QGIS software and opened the DSM file in it and it appears to be a GUI  for the same thing as this website does , Not sure how to get this from an image to values.

[image: This is how it looks in QGIS]

- Tried using gdal python package to open this DSM .tif file and it
  throws exceptions.

Note: I am not from this field and have limited knowledge mostly only Python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To read your raster into a numpy Array you can try:

```
import gdal
ds = gdal.Open(r'C:\path\to\raster\dsm.tif')
band1 = ds.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray()
```